# Edit an item in my inventory database using php Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model, routes, controller

I am having an issue where I want to edit an item in my inventory list and am able to click on the edit button but nothing happens in the browser. I am confused as to why that is.
Any thoughts would be very helpful.
My controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Inventory;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/**
 * Class InventoryController
 */
class InventoryController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Get the list of inventories.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $inventories = Inventory::all();
        return view('pages.inventories',[
            "inventories" => $inventories
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the generated inventory
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('pages.inventories.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created inventory
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validate([
            'title'=> 'required|string',
            'description'=> 'required|string|max:300',
            'price' => 'required|integer|min:0',
            'in_stock' => 'required|integer',
            'on_sale' => 'required|boolean'
        ]);
        $inventory = new Inventory();

        $inventory->fill($validated)->save();

        return redirect('/inventories');
    }

    /**
     * Editing existing inventory
     *
     * @param $inventory
     *
     */
    public function edit(Request $request, Inventory $inventory)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title'=> 'required|string',
            'description'=> 'required|string|max:300',
            'price' => 'required|integer|min:0',
            'in_stock' => 'required|integer',
            'on_sale' => 'required|boolean'
        ]);
        $inventory = Inventory::find('id');
        $inventory->title = $request->input('title');
        $inventory->description = $request->input('description');
        $inventory->price = $request->input('price');
        $inventory->in_stock = $request->input('in_stock');
        $inventory->on_sale = $request->input('on_sale');
        $inventory->fill($validated)->save();
        return view('pages.inventories.edit',['inventory' => $inventory])->with('Item has been updated!' . $request->input('title'));


    }
```

My inventories blade file:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'My Inventory')

@section('content')
    <h1>Inventory Table</h1>
    <p>This is the inventory table made using PHP Laravel that is randomly generated.</p>
   <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>In stock</th>
                <th>On sale</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($inventories as $inventory)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$inventory->id}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory->title}}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory->description}}</td>
                <td> &pound;{{ number_format($inventory->price, 2) }}</td>
                <td>{{$inventory->in_stock}}</td>
                <td>{{ $inventory->on_sale ? 'Yes' : 'No' }}</td>
                <td><a href="{{ route('inventories.edit', $inventory) }}">Edit</a></td>
                <td><a href="{{ route('inventories.destroy', $inventory) }}">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
@endsection
```

My router:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', [\App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('pages.index');

Route::get('/inventories', [\App\Http\Controllers\InventoryController::class, 'index'])->name('index');

Route::get('/inventories/create', [\App\Http\Controllers\InventoryController::class, 'create']);

Route::post('/inventories', [\App\Http\Controllers\InventoryController::class, 'store']);


Route::get('/inventory/{inventory}/edit',[\App\Http\Controllers\InventoryController::class, 'edit'])->name('inventories.edit');

Route::patch('/inventories/{inventory}',[\App\Http\Controllers\InventoryController::class, 'edit'])->name('inventories.update');

Route::get('/inventories/{inventory}',[\App\Http\Controllers\InventoryController::class, 'delete'])->name('inventories.destroy');

Route::delete('/inventories/{inventory}', [\App\Http\Controllers\InventoryController::class, 'delete'])->name('inventories.destroy');
```

My Inventory Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Inventory extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'on_sale' => 'boolean',
    ];

    /**
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'description',
        'price',
        'in_stock',
        'on_sale'
    ];

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $guarded = [];

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
}
```

My edit blade file:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Create Inventory')

@section('menu')

@section('content')
    <h1><strong>Edit {{ $inventory->title }}</strong></h1>
    <x-inventory-form :inventory=$inventory />
@endsection
```

The goal is to have a user wish to edit an item from the list of inventory on my database and be able to change the title, description, price, whether its in stock or on sale, then validate it and if it is validated update the item with a success message so the user knows they were successful.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a view things. First of all you're missing some routes. The easiest way to create all those routes is using `Route::resource('inventory', 'inventoryController');`

When you've setup the routes, you will need a separate function for the get and post of the update. So you'll need `public function edit(Request $request, Inventory $inventory)` you already have but change the name to 'update' and you'll need a `public function edit($id)` which will show the edit page (so you've go get the inventory item information and parse it to the view)

For more information you could take a look in the docs https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#resource-controllers